# apt-get remove libstdc++-4.8-doc | 101MB will be freed?

Tags: apt, package-management

Here's the output of `apt-get remove libstdc++-4.8-doc` on my system.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libstdc++-4.8-doc 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libstdc++-4.8-doc
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 101 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 272370 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libstdc++-4.8-doc (4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
```

As you can see, `apt-get` claims that 101 MB would be freed on removing the package. Here's the output of `apt-get install libstdc++-4.8-doc`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++-4.8-doc 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libstdc++-4.8-doc
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/9,891 kB of archives.
After this operation, 101 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libstdc++-4.8-doc.
(Reading database ... 263557 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libstdc++-4.8-doc_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++-4.8-doc (4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libstdc++-4.8-doc (4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ...
```

The installation(.deb) file is only around 9,819 kB. How does the file bloat to such a large extent on installation ?

Comment: That makes no sense at all. Infact, all the package contains is documentation which shouldn't use up a lot of space. That makes me think this is an apt bug. But that's my guess.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to me. Debian packaging uses compression (usually Gzip), and a package which is almost entirely text (like doc packages) will high compression ratios. I'm slightly surprised it's only 1:10.

On closer inspection, the HTML documentation included in the package (which are more compete than the man pages) take about 115MB. It includes a lot of images, which might be the reason. Now I am surprised the compression ratio reached 1:10.

Answer (score 0):

### Downloaded/cached size != Installed size

When you run `sudo apt-get install libstdc++-4.8-doc` then it says:

1. > Need to get 0 B/9,891 kB of archives.

   `apt-get install` downloads deb archives from repository to **cache directory** `/var/cache/apt/archives` but here  `0 B/9,891 kB` means required archives (here 9,891 kB of deb) are already exist in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. so there is nothing to download from repository
2. > After this operation, 101 MB of additional disk space will be used.

   Which means **for installing (after downloading 9,891 kB of archives)** 101MB disk space will be used, because after deb packages downloaded by `apt` it is installed by `dpkg` to your system which creates libraries and binaries + shared files usually in `/usr/lib`, `/usr/bin` & `/usr/share`

As well as When you run `sudo apt-get remove libstdc++-4.8-doc` it says :

> After this operation, 101 MB disk space will be freed.

Which means all files installed by this packages is removed with package (except config because `purge` not used) which is about of 101MB ; say **installed 101MB will be freed**

- **But one problem is** : cached (9,891 kB of) archives are still exist in `/var/cache/apt/archives`) so run following command to clean them:

  ```
  sudo apt-get clean
  ```

Hope this would help you to understand correctly why there is difference quotes.

---

Additional Info: [Deb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) is compressed archives so it consume less space ; you will see **`Unpacking libstdc++-4.8-doc (4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ...`** which means deb is unpacking by `dpkg`.

Comment: "Which means there are 9,891 kB of deb archives will be downloaded" close, but in your example _nothing_ will be downloaded since it already exists in the APT cache.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.